# Case when only returnng numeric results

Tags: sqlite

I am using a CASE WHEN statement to select alpha numeric data, but the statement will only return the rows that are numeric.

When creating the table, I defined the row as "CarPlate1" TEXT When selecting the data I run a query similar to the one below, only mine searches over several columns, ie CarPlate1, CarPlate2 and CarPlate3.

`SELECT "CarPlate1", "dbcarplate", CASE WHEN "CarPlate1" = '+readlpr+' THEN "CarPlate1"  ELSE '+null+' END dbcarplate FROM "SiteDB" ORDER BY dbcarplate DESC LIMIT 3;`

Stored alpa numeric fields return the following error message

`"Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: ABCDE1234"`

where ABCDE1234 is the data that is being searched for, but the query will produce the required results for numeric only data.

Need to get back data like ABCDEFGH, ABCDE1234, or 98341

Comment: Please try `"'+readlpr+'"`, i.e. quote the content of readlpr, in order to clarify that it is a value and not the name of a (non-existing) column.

Comment: Are you building this SQL string through application layer? Please provide fuller context.

Comment: In node red I am using JavaScript in a function node to populate a predefined query, then sending it to the SQLite node for processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a proper concatenation between strings and the variable `readlpr`:

```
"SELECT CarPlate1, dbcarplate, CASE WHEN CarPlate1 = '" + readlpr + 
"' THEN CarPlate1  ELSE 'null' END dbcarplate FROM SiteDB ORDER BY dbcarplate DESC LIMIT 3;"
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it.